# Filter not filtering from Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I am having having some trouble with a filter function that does not want to do what I need it to do.

I need this array to be filtered for strings within it that contain consecutive repeats of the same letter.

This is what I have:

```
var regex = /(.)\1+/g;

var filtered = permutations.filter(function(string){
    return !string.match(regex);
  });
```

Where permutations is equal to

`["a,a,b", "a,a,b", "b,a,a", "a,b,a", "a,b,a", "b,a,a"]`

The output for this just shows the same:

`["a,a,b", "a,a,b", "b,a,a", "a,b,a", "a,b,a", "b,a,a"]`

The output **should** be:

`["a,b,a","a,b,a"]`

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe you want to find non-consecutive duped chars? Use `/(.).*\1/` with `RegExp#test(String)`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew is that not what /(.)\1+/g does?

Comment: No, your pattern matches strings like `nnnnn` (or finds such partialmatches in longer strings).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Ooh I see, i need the duped characters to be consecutive, hence why \1+ is used

Comment: Ok, you need `/(.),\1/`

Comment: That worked! Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you need to match a repeated char *after a comma*, thus, change your pattern to

```
/(.),\1/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FbogqE/1)

**Details**:

- `(.)` - Capturing group matching a single char other than a line break char
- `,` - a comma
- `\1` - backreference to capture group 1.

```js
var regex = /(.),\1/;
var permutations = ["a,a,b", "a,a,b", "b,a,a", "a,b,a", "a,b,a", "b,a,a"];
var filtered = permutations.filter(function(string){
   return !regex.test(string);
});
console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: I actually realized why my original wasn't working earlier! I forgot to turn each of them back into non-comma separated strings, which is the typical way to do that.

Anyway, thanks for the help!

Comment: Then, you'd use `var regex = /(.)\1/` and `return !regex.test(string.replace(/,/g,''))`. With my approach, you save one regex replacement.